# show keypad when entering time instead of only rotary, iOS 14 Swift 5

Tags: ios, xcode, datepicker, keypad

I want to be able to set the time via a test input like we do when setting the alarm in the phone itself, I have set it to compact and it shows the same wheel type view as the alarm setting one but it doesn't show a keypad, it only allows me to rotate the numbers. is there a way to be able to do both like in the alarm setting part of the phone?

I want this
[image: What I Want]

but get this
[image: What I get]

here is my code

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.time
 
 if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
      datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .automatic
 } else {
      // Fallback on earlier versions
 }
 
    datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
    dateLabel.inputView = datePicker
```